# Making a randomized string cycling guessing console program guess one character at a time instead of all at once

Tags: c#, console-application

The code is designed to start by making a randomized string of characters, which has a user-chosen number of characters. Then, it will cycle through characters randomly until a character matches the string, in which case it locks it and colours it cyan. Any characters already tried for a string are ignored.

The issue is in the program guessing all the characters simultaneously, instead of guessing one-by-one and continuing to the next character once it finishes the current one, as intended. This results in the differences between completing a smaller string and a longer string is logarithmic instead of additive.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Random random = new Random();
        public static string RandomString(int length)
        {
            const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Console.WriteLine("How many characters in the password?");
            string delta = Console.ReadLine();

            try
            {
                int passwordlength = Convert.ToInt32(delta);

                // BARRIER

                string password = RandomString(passwordlength);

                Random r = new Random();
                string letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
                List<string> dictionary = new List<string>(new string[] { password });

                string word = dictionary[r.Next(dictionary.Count)];
                List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append(letters[r.Next(letters.Length)]);
                    if (sb[i] != word[i])
                    {
                        indexes.Add(i);

                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

                var charsToGuessByIndex = indexes.ToDictionary(k => k, v => letters);

                while (indexes.Count > 0)
                {
                    int index;

                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                    Console.Clear();

                    for (int i = indexes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        index = indexes[i];

                        var charsToGuess = charsToGuessByIndex[index];
                        sb[index] = charsToGuess[r.Next(charsToGuess.Length)];
                        charsToGuessByIndex[index] = charsToGuess.Remove(charsToGuess.IndexOf(sb[index]), 1);
                        if (sb[index] == word[index])
                        {
                            indexes.RemoveAt(i);
                        }
                    }
                    var output = sb.ToString();

                    for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (indexes.Contains(i))
                        {
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                        }

                        Console.Write(output[i]);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

                Console.WriteLine("Password successfully breached. Have a nice day.");                    
                Console.WriteLine("");

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch
            {
                if (delta is string)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("FATAL ERROR PRESS ENTER TO EXIT");


                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("welp, it was worth a try.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: Please go through your code and remove everything not necessary. The time it takes to skim, read, and understand your question is opposite to the number of answers and the quality of the answers you get. Also; when you reduce and reduce and reduce the code to the point where it explains the problem and nothing else - there is a good chance you have found the solution yourself. The latter is not to be rude but to show a good side effect of reducing a problem.

Comment: @JakeTheFlyingFox  is my Answer working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Random random = new Random();
        static string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

        public static string generatePassword(int length)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(chars.OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()).First());
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static StringBuilder generateNotPassword(int length, string password)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(chars.Where(w => password[i] != w).OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()).First());
            }
            return sb;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many characters in the password?");
            var passwordlength = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            var password = generatePassword(passwordlength);
            var notPassword = generateNotPassword(passwordlength, password);

            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < passwordlength; i++)
            {
                var notfound = true;
                while (notfound)
                {

                    foreach (var c in chars)
                    {
                        if (password[i] == c)
                        {
                            notPassword[i] = c;
                            notfound = false;
                        }
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                        Console.Clear();
                        var output = notPassword.ToString();
                        for (int ii = 0; ii < output.Length; ii++)
                        {
                            var iii = (!notfound && i == ii) ? ii - 1 : ii;
                            Console.ForegroundColor = i > iii ? ConsoleColor.Red : ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                            var o = i <= iii ? '█' : output[ii];
                            Console.Write(o);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                        Console.WriteLine
                            (String.Format(
                           "RunTime {0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                           ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10));
                        if (!notfound) break;
                    }


                }
            }
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

            Console.WriteLine($"Guessed  Password = {notPassword}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Original Password = {password}");
            //https://www.asciiart.eu/electronics/electronics
            Console.WriteLine(@"
                                  ____
                             ____|    \
                            (____|     `._____
                             ____|       _|___
                            (____|     .'
                                 |____/

                            ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you need more help ?

Comment: It seems the code crashes if any of the initial characters (immediately after inputting a number) match the password. As well, the code is decoding from right-to-left instead of left-to-right.

Comment: Maybe making the initial guess a series of █ characters instead of guessable characters would help.

Comment: The program ends instantly once it starts the last 2 characters of the code.